# change default font in spreadjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, spreadsheet, spreadjs

How to change the default font in the toolbar of spreadjs? I tried it with the below code. But it didn't
working.

```
        var active = spread.getActiveSheet();
        sheetstyle.font = "8pt Arial";

        active.setDefaultStyle(sheetstyle, GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.viewport);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
GC.Spread.Sheets.Themes.Office.bodyFont("Arial")
```